# Visual Studio Code - React web app not launching w/ debugger due to corrupted appdata file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, userappdatapath

- I have a React web app.
- The app launches and runs just fine when i execu "yarn start" from the terminal (with not debugger attached to it).
- When I launch from the VSC debugger the UI just spins, doesn't even execute/load the app itself (i run from VSC so i can debug).

This wasn't always the case. I suspect a recent Windows update, or, most likely an update to Visual Studio Code itself caused something to be screwed up.

I noticed that I could get the VSC debugger to launch the UI after i delete Visual Studio Code's respective folder under AppData (appdata\roaming\code\user\workspaceStorage<some GUID-like foldername>.

Unfortunately now it seems that not even deleting this appData folder doesnt work either.

**Question:**

Has anybody experiences a similar issue?

Comment: Does this happen with a fresh, empty/basic react project? ([mre])